# Building native blog app in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, api

I am building a blog app for a website and I'm looking how others are approaching it. I have JSON data with the following fields:

- Title
- Date
- Author
- Featured Image
- Post Content

I have a UITableViewController as the main view and I can format the table cell no problem with title, featured image etc...

What I want to know is how people approach the interior view. The view when you click on one of the articles? When you view Business insider, New york times, Mashable, Tech Crunch etc.. their interiors are well formatted.

The JSON data I have has divs and classes that WordPress automatically includes in their posts.

My question is, how are they formatting the content that is provided by JSON? How are they including the styles? Or do they create a stripped down version on their server and displaying it in UIWebView?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Post Content is marked up in HTML. You can parse and display that in a UITextView. First you should drag a UITextView onto the view controller you want to display the post content. Create an IBOutlet called something like "textView." Then you can say something like:

```
   let postContentAttributedString = try! NSAttributedString(data:(postContent as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:NSUTF8StringEncoding], documentAttributes: nil)
   self.textView.attributedString = postContentAttributedString
```